# Why does this code execute two branches of if...else in VS Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've met some problem in debug some code in vs2013/2015/2008.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int mode = 1;
int size = 1;

if (mode == 0)
{
    cout << "mode = 0" << endl;
}
else
{
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            cout << "mode=1,size=1" << endl; //in debug mode will execute this sentence                                         
        }
        else
            return 0;  //however,when I Step in (F10),this will also be executed but have no influence.But When I insert a breakpoint in there and press F5, will not break in there 
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        if (size > 0)
        {
            cout << "mode=2,size=1" << endl;
        }
        else
            return 0;

    }
}


return 1;}
```

[image]
[image]

So, how to explain this phenomenon? Does it have any problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem you're running into is. Can you explain it in more detail please?

Comment: You can see the pic1 and pic2,  and try to   execute the code step by step

Comment: You can use the disassembly window to find out more about what's actually being executed :)

Comment: also see a similar question I had some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427455/strange-looping-at-end-of-function-body-call-c

Answer (score 0):

This is how the debugger works in VS 2015. Ignore it.

`return 0;` isn't executed, even if it looks like it. Weird behavior, I was surprised by that too.

They should have made the arrow go to the `else` statement, not the first line *after* it, but for some reason they didn't.

Just ignore it. You can make a feature request if you want too :)

Comment: How can this happened?Is there some problems in compiler,or something?

Comment: @ZhengOniliste It's just a feature.